# deploying WAR and EJB-jar files separately

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have an application which I am deploying on `GlassFish`. It has an *EJB-tier* with (JPA) Entites and EJBs to get access and write to the database and it has 3 (independent) web apps. Everything is built with `Maven`.

```
ServerApplication 
  |
  +-ServerApplication-ear
  +-ServerApplication-ejb
  |
  +-GrumpyCat (war)
  +-HummingBird (war)
  +-Koala (war)
```

All three `war` projects depend on the `ejb` project. When compiling/building the ear, it copies the `war` files to the `ear` project and then I can deploy the `ear` file on `GlassFish`.

This works fine, all 4 modules (the ejb, and the 3 war) get deployed without problems and I can access the 3 `war` projects like:

```
myServer.com/GrumpyCat
myServer.com/HummingBird
myServer.com/Koala
```

My problem is, that I can't deploy a single `war` project on its own. For example when I change something in the `koala` project, I would like to be able to build only the koala.war and deploy it on the server, without having to upload and deploy the complete `ear` file.

But when deploying, GlassFish tells me either :

- there is already a project deployed on `Koala` (true, it was deployed together with the ear)
- or (when I change the build-version) it doesn't *"know"* the ejbs and I get a number of `ClassNotFound` Exceptions.

Is there a way to deploy the modules of the application one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is the way to go if you really want to deploy them individually.  However, you are seeing a `ClassNotFound` exception because the WARs are individual projects and as such don't have access to the EAR's class path.

To make that work, you have to add the public API of your application to your WAR's classpath.  The public API consists of at least the EJB's remote interfaces of the EJBS that you would like to access from the WAR and any DTOs used in your API.

The easiest way is to create a separate package (such as `com.example.api`) and let a build tools such as ant or Maven bundle that api package together with your EJBs and your WARs, or you create a `myapp-api.jar` and include it in the respective class-paths.

Then you can remove the WARs from the EAR and deploy them as separate projects.

Comment: Thanks! sounds very promising. I will have to read up on the remote interface though and I hope I am not creating my own bottleneck :)

Comment: If you deploy them to the same server, it's still local (in the same JVM) and there should be no bottleneck, even though it's called "remote".